# Using the mouse wheel to scroll a browser window horizontally

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a very wide website, intentionally designed to have no vertical scrolling but a lot of horizontal.

Scrolling horizontally is usually a pain to users so was wondering if there was some way of using the middle mouse or other scrolling habits (eg. page up/down, up/down arrows, middle mouse click/drag) to scroll horizontally instead of vertically.

**Edit:** The main reason for requiring horizontal scrolling is because the layout/approach is a left to right graphical/interactive timeline. I've since found some examples;

This one with MooTools: http://www.tinkainteractive.com.au/ and a few other examples I found at http://naldzgraphics.net/inspirations/40-examples-of-horizontal-scrolling-websites/

Comment: I have a client who also insists on limiting vertical scrolling.  I don't get it; with the scroll button on a mouse vertical scrolling is easy.  I also see a trend toward more scrolling on the web (e.g. SO, thesixtyone.com, to list only two) and I like it.  So, why are you limiting vertical scrolling.

Comment: this answer seems better https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785695/4770754

Answer (score 6):

You can add your own event listener

```
document.onmousewheel = myScrollFunction
```

Scrolling can be done by

```
window.scrollBy(x, y)
```

Where x is the horizontal scrolling offset and y the vertical scrolling offset.

So you might just call this function in your event listener. You may have to stop bubbling with event.stopPropagation and prevent browser default behaviour with event.preventDefault so that the original scrolling behaviour doesn't get applied anymore.

---

Edit: I was curious about this so I implemented something :-)

```
function onScroll(event) {
  // delta is +120 when scrolling up, -120 when scrolling down
  var delta = event.detail ? event.detail * (-120) : event.wheelDelta
  // set own scrolling offset, take inverted sign from delta (scroll down should scroll right,
  // not left and vice versa
  var scrollOffset = 10 * (delta / -120);
  // Scroll it
  window.scrollBy(scrollOffset, 0);
  // Not sure if the following two are necessary, you may have to evaluate this
  event.preventDefault;
  event.stopPropagation;
}

// The not so funny part... fin the right event for every browser
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
if (document.attachEvent) 
  document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, onScroll);  
else if (document.addEventListener)
  document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, onScroll, false);
```

This works in Firefox 3.5 and Opera 10, however not in IE8. But that would be your part now... ;-)

Comment: Yuck, checking the user agent to add js enhancements :/

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't change this behaviour. It would be very unexpected to the user. Maybe it makes sense to cover the symptom and re-layout your website to switch to a more vertical centered approach?

Still you can do loads of event-handling stuff with java-script, but as said I would rethink the layout.

Comment: I disagree. Horizontal sites are of a very unique style. I think using the scroll wheel to properly scroll left to right would not confuse the user much if at all.

Comment: any answer that is "why would you want to do that?" deserves a downvote.  Maybe your PM has told you it has to be this way, a customer wants it.  Can't say "why would you want to do that?" and lose the client.