# Horizontal scrolling parallax with mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm using jquery Scrolling Parallax plugin, in particular the option shown in:
http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/examples/multi-directional-parallax

The layers move on both directions (vertical and horizontal), but when I use mouse wheel I would like to have horizontal scrolling instead of vertical scrolling.

Thank you for any suggestion,
regards Marco

Comment: Until now I haven't tried any customization; The question is how to achieve horizontal scrolling of layers, while using mouse wheel

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/ Google is quite easy to use. "Horizontal mouse wheel" -> #1 result. Update: And result #2 is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll - pretty simple :)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, actually I had a look at this plugin, but it seems that the online demo itself    http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/    doesn't work with firefox, opera, IE