# How to trigger javascript mouse scroll wheel on a divs horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a nested div that are larger. The overflow-x is set to auto, such a scroll bare appears. I would like to make such that if the user scrolls(with the mouse wheel) within the div, the scrollbar scrolls horizontal.

```
<div id="outer" style="width:1000px;overflow-x:auto">
      <div id="inner" style="width:2000px"></div>
</div>
```

What kind of javascript is needed for this. Remember that the scrollbar comes automatic, not looking for a solution with javascript changing left/right positions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why changing scrollLeft doesn't fit you?

```
document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (e.wheelDelta);
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I saw some solutions using css position and changing the left and right, paddings and such to simulate scrolling. But this works nice. thanks