# Scroll for overflow-x by mousewheel

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow, mousewheel

Scroll for overflow-x by mousewheel

hi every body
i have a div width overflow-x
this div is my main div
overflow-x work good , but when use mousewheel nothing happen
how i can use mousewheel for scroll this element

```
.Main{
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you should give a height and width

Answer (score 0):

`.Main` should have content overflowing along x for you to be able to scroll.

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qt2A/show/)

```
#two {
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 200px; width: 20000px;
}
#one {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

---

```
<div id="one"><div id="two"></div></div>
```

Comment: i know that , scrolling horizontally work good ,my problem is scroll dont work with mousewheel , however tnx for your answer

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll