# How to scroll right and left by mouse scroll button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[jsfiddle example1](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWp9/4/)
[example2](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ebs5/2/show/)

I have div with text inside,
I want when the user will turn around the mouse scroll button ,all the div will slide to left or right
insted top and down,

I try to write some code and I dont know how to continue from here.
many thanks for any help.

this my code.

javascript code:

```
var valueToScroll = 0; 
$('#divScroll').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {

            $(this).scrollLeft(++valueToScroll);
        }
        else{
            $(this).scrollRight(--valueToScroll);
        }
    });
```

css code:

```
div{
    width:2000px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="divScroll">There is a substantial disparity of 13-17% between the earnings of men and women in the same positions and at similar skill levels, according to a new study by the National Insurance Institute, seeking to examine the socio-economic status of women in Israel between in the years 1997-2011.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 document.body.doScroll(event.wheelDelta>0?"left":"right");
```

## Fiddle update

http://jsfiddle.net/fc7yy/

## Please credit

Andy E from here: [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)