# Scroll horizontally instead of vertically in certain div with images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried many solutions I found on the web. None worked. I'm trying to make a website scroll horizontally when I'm scrolling vertically. I tried to accomplish this via js - nothing. Then I read that I should be able to do this simply using css. Again - nothing. Here's the code as it is right now:

```
<style type="text/css">
#b {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    font-size:0;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#b img {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="b">
        <img src="a.jpg"/>
        <img src="b.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

What is wrong? / What can I do?

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: What do you mean? You may just copy the above?

Comment: seems duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll

Comment: Tip: If you use proper indentation, we might actually read the code in your question. :)

Comment: so, did you make it work ? which solution work for you ?

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer doesn't work in my browser (FireFox).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/4/) is a solution I've gotten to work pretty nicely.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="b">
        <div class="img_holder">
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
            <img/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When you scroll, you are essentially moving `.img_holder` left and right within `#b`.  This method requires that `.img_holder` is as wide (or wider) than the sum of the images you'll be placing in it, as well as all the padding and margins.  `#b` is the desired width to be viewed on the page.

**CSS:**

```
#b {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.img_holder {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 910px;
}
img {
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #123;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var scroller = {};
scroller.e = document.getElementById("b");

if (scroller.e.addEventListener) {
    scroller.e.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    scroller.e.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
} else scroller.e.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

    // cross-browser wheel delta
    var e = window.event || e;
    var delta = - 20 * (Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail))));

    var pst = $('#b').scrollLeft() + delta;

    if (pst < 0) {
        pst = 0;
    } else if (pst > $('.img_holder').width()) {
        pst = $('.img_holder').width();
    }

    $('#b').scrollLeft(pst);

    return false;
}
```

Make sure that you use conditions to stop from scrolling below zero and above the max width of the container (`if` conditions near bottom of code).  Also, the `delta` value when scrolling is very small, and so to prevent the user from having to scroll a bunch I've multiplied it by 20.  You can choose any value you'd like to adjust scrolling speed.

Also works nicely if you want to hide the horizontal Scroll Bar:

```
#b {
    overflow-x:hidden:
}
```

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/5/)

Comment: And it doesn't require any external JS files to be included, other than JQuery.

Comment: Great!, can you please: put it a slider ?, and you make the content bigger?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/4/) fiddle has a slider, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/5/) one doesn't.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/6/) is one with larger images within.  Make sure to increase the size of all the divs, especially the width of `.img_holder`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

Example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

Code: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

})
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. The example doesn't work for me?! (Using iceweasel/firefox.)

Comment: This basically worked! But instead of jquery.mousewheel.min.js I used jquery.mousewheel.js

Comment: This method doesn't work on my system.  The solution shouldn't be browser-dependent. "Try Chrome" is not a solution - you can't ask all the viewers of your site to download a new browser just so the site works properly.  Refer to my answer for a complete solution that is browser-independent.

Comment: This wasn't browser-independent. However, using jquery.mousewheel.js instead made it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this one:

```
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 80px;
    white-space:nowrap
}
.imageDiv img {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    vertical-align:top;
 }
```