# Horizontal Scroll with MouseWheel in GWT ScrollPanel?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I have a GWT ScrollPanel with a horizontal scrollbar, i.e.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

**How can I bind a MouseWheel event on the scroll bar to perform a horizontal scrolling when the mouse wheel is moved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example of how to listen to a mouse wheel event:
http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Listeners~MouseWheelListener

Instead of a label extend a `ScrollPanel`

Instead of `setText` call `setHorizontalScrollPosition(int position)`

```
public void onMouseWheel(Widget sender, MouseWheelVelocity velocity)
{
    DOM.eventPreventDefault(DOM.eventGetCurrentEvent()); //prevent vertical scroll
    int positionDelta = velocity.getDeltaY() * 30;
    int newPosition = getHorizontalScrollPosition() - positionDelta;
    setHorizontalScrollPosition(newPosition);   
}
```

Also see [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)