# jQuery On scroll go to the next section in a horizontal website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making this horizontal website but i'm having a problem with scroll:

In Windows it's ok, but in Mac Mavericks there's a scroll acceleration, which makes the page scrolls too fast.

The solution i found is to jump to next session on scroll, is it even possible?

This is my website: http://www.finecolor.com.br/bandainky

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

normally I would advise to use the following snippet to remap vertical scrolling to horizontal:

```
document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function ()
{
    if (document.body.doScroll)
        document.body.doScroll(event.wheelDelta>0?"left":"right");

    return false;
}
```

fully hijacking the scroll like the library you use does tends to be bad for UX. Here is a full post on how to do that properly: [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll)