# How to scroll horizontal Only div on mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML markup:

```
<div class="big">
  long width text
</div>
```

CSS rule:

```
.big{
    height:200px;
    background: red;
}
```

How to scroll horizontal Only BIG div on mouse wheel http://jsfiddle.net/cxD55/

Comment: [How to do a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll?rq=1)

Comment: but this is the whole page, i want to scroll only red div because if i add elements in my page they will scroll too, but i need to scroll onle one div

Comment: Are you looking for something like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/4xc67/)

Answer (score 2):

Set the [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) CSS style but leave the overflow-y style set to visible.

Comment: Ah, Deb's link suggests I've misunderstood the question, is that right?

Comment: No, i want to scroll red div on mouse wheel

Comment: Ah, then remove the scroll bars from the page by setting `overflow: hidden` on the `html` and `body` elements, then capture [mouse wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) events on the page and set the [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft) property of the div. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**Html**

```
<div class="big">
long text here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big {
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
width:6000px;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
} else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
}
})();
```

Change `width` according to your need.

Comment: It will be good if you share the demo because I tried your code and It's not working.It should be scroll using the mouse wheel. right?