# How to move left to right a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I would like to animate in js a simple div on scroll as you can find here [grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/new/#radio).

As you can see, the animation reacts to scroll up/down and move horizontally. 
This is typically what I need. How can I easily determine this feature in js? Thanks

Comment: what you tried till ?

Comment: Have you tried google?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346958/how-to-do-a-horizontal-scroll-on-mouse-wheel-scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called **parallax**.

You can achieve this yourself using a combination of CSS attribute changes and scroll detection events, or just use a plugin like SkrollR http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

For this particular example, you can see the inline styles of that div being changed on scroll (in developer tools):

```
<div class="albums-holder" style="background-position: 1174px 50%;">...
```

You can do this on the scroll event:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".albums-holder").css( "background-position", [VALUE]);
});
```

Where `[VALUE]` would be computed by incrementing/decrementing the background-position by a value each time.

*EDIT: I failed to mention, my answer is based on the assumption you have jQuery on the page, I would recommend it is for tasks like this anyway.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for this full reply !

Comment: No problem mate, nice site by the way, nice and simple.